# Attempt at Proving a Theorem about Integrals

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

Let $f,g$ $[a,b]$ $\rightarrow$ $\mathbb{R}$ two continuous functions ang $g$ positive. Show that there exists $\xi$ $\in$ $[a,b]$ such that $\int_a^b f(x)g(x)dx$ = $f(\xi) \int_a^b g(x)dx$

**attempt at proof**

The intermediate theorem for integrals implies that: $\exists$ $\xi$ $\in$ $[a,b]$ such that:

$\int_a^b f(x)g(x)dx$ = $f(\xi)g(\xi)(b-a)$

But we have $g(\xi)(b-a)$ = $\int_a^b g(x)dx$

Therefore $f(\xi)g(\xi)(b-a)$ = $f(\xi)\int_a^b g(x)dx$

Is that proof valid?

And if not, what's a valid proof?

Comment: It's not valid, the points $\xi$ and $\zeta$ with $\int_a^b f(x)g(x)\,dx = f(\xi)g(\xi)(b-a)$ and $\int_a^b g(x)\,dx = g(\zeta)(b-a)$ generally aren't the same. Note that $m \leqslant f(x) \leqslant M \implies mg(x) \leqslant f(x)g(x) \leqslant Mg(x)$.

Comment: The proof is invalid since the "$\xi$'s" are different.

Comment: When you say "But we have..." there is a mistake: there is no reason to believe in $g( \xi) (b-a)= \int_a^b g(t) dt$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

Note that since $g(x)>0$, and then $$\inf_{x\in[a,b]}\{f(x)\}\,g(x)\le f(x)\,g(x)\le \sup_{x\in[a,b]}\{f(x)\}\,g(x) \tag 1$$

Then, apply the intermediate value theorem to the continuous function $f$.

**SPOILER ALERT:**  Scroll over the highlighted area to reveal the solution

> Let $m=\min_{x\in[a,b]}\{f(x)\}$ and $M=\max_{x\in[a,b]}\{f(x)\}$.  Using $(1)$ we can write $$m \le \frac{\int_a^b f(x)\,g(x)\,dx}{\int_a^b g(x)\,dx}\le M\tag 2$$From the intermediate value theorem, for any number $I$ such that $m\le I\le M$, there exists a number $\xi \in(a,b)$ such that $f(\xi)=I$.  Applying this to $(2)$ we find that there exists a $\xi\in(a,b)$ such that $$f(\xi)=\frac{\int_a^b f(x)\,g(x)\,dx}{\int_a^b g(x)\,dx} \tag 3$$Multiplying both sides of $(3)$ by the positive number $\int_a^b g(x)\,dx$ yields the coveted result $$\int_a^b f(x)\,g(x)\,dx=f(\xi)\int_a^bg(x)\,dx$$ for some $\xi\in(a,b)$ as was to be shown!

Comment: how did you pass from 1 to 2, how did you get $m \le \frac{\int_a^b f(x)\,g(x)\,dx}{\int_a^b g(x)\,dx}\le M\tag 2$ from 1?

Comment: Since $f$ is continuous, its infimum and supremum are its minimum and maximum, respectively.   Then, since $g>0$, $mg\le fg\le Mg$ and $\int_a^b mg(x)\,dx\le \int_a^b f(x)g(x)\,dx\le \int_a^b Mg(x)\,dx$.